# What is default destructor if a class inherits from a pure base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer

Considering next two classes :

```
struct Base
{
  virtual ~Base()
  {
  }

  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
  virtual void foo()
  {
  }
};
```

Is the following causing an undefined behaviour :

```
Base *obj = new Derived;
delete obj;
```

?

Additional question : how come that one a method is declared virtual, it is virtual in derived classes (even if the virtual keyword is not used in the derived class), but it is not true for destructors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the following causing an undefined behaviour :

No, that is not invoking undefined behaviour *precisely* because the destructor of `Base` is `virtual`.

---

EDIT: Its just to clarify a doubt (raised in the following comment), and to emphasize what I said above.

@Oli Charlesworth commented:

> Technically, even if it were not declared virtual, the behaviour would **not** be undefined, it would just be undesirable.

No. The behavior would be undefined.

The section §5.3.5/3 from the Standard says,

> In the first alternative (delete
>   object), if the static type of the
>   operand is different from its dynamic
>   type, the static type shall be a base
>   class of the operand’s dynamic type
>   and the static type shall have a
>   virtual destructor **or the behavior
>   is undefined.** In the second alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the
>   object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.

I think it helps removing the doubt.:-)

Comment: Technically, even if it were not declared `virtual`, the behaviour would not be *undefined*, it would just be undesirable.

Comment: @Oli: I deleted the other duplicate post. :D, My net is slow today, and when I clicked on "submit" (most likely more than once) and it resubmitted my post.

Comment: @Oli: Is your comment supported by the Standard?

Comment: @Oli undesirable in which way? :)

Comment: @Nawaz: Ah, I hadn't seen that quote before.  Interesting.  So +1.

Comment: @VJo: As it turns out, it is indeed undefined.  But in the general case, undesirable, as any resource owned by the derived class will not be released.

Answer (score 2):

That is not undefined behaviour.  You've declared the base-class destructor as `virtual`, so at runtime, `delete obj` will first invoke the "default" destructor in `Derived` (as you haven't explicitly declared one), and then the destructor in `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

For any class, constructors and destructors **aren't** inherited. This is specified in the standard. As such, your code won't cause undefined behaviour, as it will invoke the default constructor/destructor for the class.
It is for this reason that inheritence doesn't hold true for destructors/constructors. It doesn't make sense for a constructor/destructor to be inherited from a parent object, as this object could potentially have all forms of different members.

Comment: Uh, it was an attempt to address the second half of his question, however it doesn't address the first half - I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: Hopefully this edit cleared up clarity issues. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have declared the base class's destructor as virtual, there is no undefined behavior here.

The statments :

```
Base *obj = new Derived;
delete obj;
```

will lead to call the derived class's desctructor and then the Base class's destructor. I didn't get the second question though